# Map: GMS works, HMS dont; onMapReady not called

Tags: android, maps, huawei-mobile-services, gmsmapview, huawei-developers

I have both GMS and HMS in one android project. GMS version works, but HMS dont call the onMapReady callback. This is the code:

```
    private var mMap: HuaweiMap? = null
    private var mapFragment: SupportMapFragment? = null

 private fun setMapFragment() {
        mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
        mapFragment!!.getMapAsync(this)
        mapFragment!!.view!!.isClickable = false
    }

    override fun onMapReady(huaweiMap: HuaweiMap) {
        mMap = huaweiMap
        loadMap()
    }
```

I thought GMS and HMS was implemented the same way, but i guess i am wrong. Does HMS need more permissions than GMS or something to make it work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is a known bug and it will be rectified on November 9, 2020.

Currently, workarounds can be used:

1. Change [SupportMapFragement](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/supportmapfragment-0000001050153243-V5?ha_source=hms1) to [MapView](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/mapview-0000001050150338-V5?ha_source=hms1).
2. Roll back the SDK version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you implemented OnMapReadyCallback also you need to pass Bundle in onCreate map methode before calling `mapFragment!!.getMapAsync(this)` :

```
 val mapViewBundle: Bundle? = null
 mapFragment!!.onCreate(mapViewBundle)
 mapFragment!!.getMapAsync(this)
```